# Grouping arrays together and sorting Multiple arrays around a chosen array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a set of different arrays that need to be grouped and sorted. However, I am unsure how I would go about grouping together the arrays so that they can be sorted. I am trying to make it so the user can choose which array within a set of grouped arrays will be the base of the sort.

By this I mean if I grouped together all the arrays titled as WS1 along with Month and Year (meaning Year, Month, afArray, rainArray, sunArray, tMaxArray, tMinArray) I would wish that I could target a certain array such as tmaxArray and sort all of the arrays to correspond with that array.

Data in the arrays would look sort of like:

```
Month     | February March   April   May     ...

Year      | 1997     1997    1997    1997

afArray   | 2        0       4       1

rainArray | 132.00   102.00  112.00  134.00
```

I'd wish that all of these arrays could be sorted according to that of (for example rainArray) leading to the output of:

```
Month     | March   April   February  May     ...

Year      | 1997    1997    1997      1997

afArray   | 0       4       2         1

rainArray | 102.00  112.00  132.00    134.00
```

Can anyone give me any advice of how I could go about doing this if it can be done? And is it possible to be able to sort those via an actual algorithm not via Visual Studios built in sorting application?

Just to give some form of extra explanation of how the system is currently built 
this is the current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;



namespace Climate_Sorting_Application
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string cont = "Y";
        public static string station;
        public static string[] monthArray = File.ReadAllLines("Month.txt");
        public static string[] yearArrayPre = File.ReadAllLines("Year.txt");
        public static int[] afArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_AF.txt").Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        public static string[] rainArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_Rain.txt");
        public static string[] sunArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_Sun.txt");
        public static string[] tmaxArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_TMax.txt");
        public static string[] tminArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_TMin.txt");
        public static string[] af2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_Rain.txt");
        public static string[] rain2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_Rain.txt");
        public static string[] sun2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_Sun.txt");
        public static string[] tmax2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_TMax.txt");
        public static string[] tmin2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_TMin.txt");
        public static string arrayToAnalyse;
        public static int t;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while(cont == "Y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please State which Station you wish to view data for");
                Console.WriteLine("Please type either 1 or 2 now then hit enter");

                station = Console.ReadLine();

                if(station == "1")
                {

                }

                if (station == "2")
                {

                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid input. Restarting process");
                    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using the Data Sorting System");
            Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to Close Program");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        private static void sortProcess()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the "base of the sort" means

Comment: Yeah I realise that didn't make much sense. I have added some additional information to try to clear things up with what I mean.

Comment: Grouped arrays are an anti-pattern. It's a sign you should create a class with a property for each of the arrays you use currently, and then have one array of the new class type.

Comment: Apologies I am not too skilled with coding yet. What exactly does that mean?

Comment: Working on it... it'll just take a few minute to get code ready in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Grouped arrays are an anti-pattern. It's a sign you should create a class with a property for each of the arrays you use currently, and then have one array of the new class type. Do this, and sorting your data becomes a simple `.OrderBy()` expression.

I wrote some code for you below, but it's all typed directly into the answer window, and even if it weren't I don't have your test data. But this should give you an idea of what you're going for... a little more code to load the data, but notice how little code you need to manipulate it once we have it ready:

```
namespace Climate_Sorting_Application
{

    public class ClimateRecord
    {
        public DateTime RecordDate {get;set;}
        public int StationId {get;set;}
        public double RainFall {get;set;}
        public double Sun {get;set;}
        public double TMax {get;set;}
        public double TMin {get;set;}
        public double AF {get;set;}

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0,-15:MMMM yyyy}{1,4}{2,8:F4}{3,8:F4}{4,8:F4}{5,8:F4}{6,8:F4}{7,8:F4}",
                RecordDate, StationId, AF, RainFail, Sun, TMax, TMin);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        static IList<ClimateRecord> LoadData()
        {
            var result = new List<ClimateRecord>();

            using (var monthRdr = new StreamReader("Month.txt"))
            using (var yearRdr = new StreamReader("Year.txt"))
            using (var afRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_AF.txt"))
            using (var rainRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_Rain.txt"))
            using (var sunRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_Sun.txt"))
            using (var tmaxRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_TMax.txt"))
            using (var tminRdr1 = new StreamReader("WS1_TMin.txt"))
            using (var afRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_AF.txt"))
            using (var rainRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_Rain.txt"))
            using (var sunRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_Sun.txt"))
            using (var tmaxRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_TMax.txt"))
            using (var tminRdr2 = new StreamReader("WS2_TMin.txt"))
            {
                 string year = yearRdr.ReadLine();
                 while (year != null)
                 {
                      var recordDate = DateTime.ParseExact(year + " " + monthRdr.ReadLine() + " 01", "yyyy MMMM dd", null)

                      var ws1 = new ClimateRecord() {
                          RecordDate = recordDate,
                          StationId = 1,
                          AF = double.Parse(afRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          Sun = double.Parse(sunRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          RainFall = double.Parse(rainRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          TMax = double.Parse(tmaxRdr1.ReadLine()),
                          TMin = double.Parse(tminRdr1.ReadLine())
                      };
                      var ws2 = new ClimateRecord() {
                          RecordDate = recordDate,
                          StationId = 2,
                          AF = double.Parse(afRdr2.ReadLine()),
                          Sun = double.Parse(sunRdr2.ReadLine()),
                          RainFall = double.Parse(rainRdr2.ReadLine()),
                          TMax = double.Parse(tmaxRdr2.ReadLine()),
                          TMin = double.Parse(tminRdr2.ReadLine())
                      };
                      result.Add(ws1);
                      result.Add(ws2);
                      year = yearRdr.ReadLine();
                 } 
            }
            return result;
        }

        static void PrintData(IEnumerable<ClimateRecord> data)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("{0,15}{1,4}{2,8}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}{6,8}{7,8}",
              "Month/Year", "WS", "AF", "Rain", "Sun", "T-Max", "T-Min");

           foreach (var record in data) Console.WriteLine(record);
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var climateData = LoadData();

            Console.WriteLine("Printing all data: ");
            PrintData(climateData);

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPrinting Station 1 data:");
            PrintData(climateData.Where(r => r.StationId == 1));

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPrinting Station 2 data:");
            PrintData(climateData.Where(r => r.StationId == 2));

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPrinting Station 1 data ordered by rainfall descending:");
            PrintData(climateData.Where(r => r.StationId == 1).OrderBy(r => r.RainFall * -1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `string item = yearRdr.ReadLine(); while (item != null)` I would recommend to use `while(!yearRdr.EndOfStream)`. To make it even more reliable in case if there is a mismatch of record counts, better to check all of the readers' EndOfStream.

Comment: Currently the only error I can see with the code is when I put it into Visual Studio I receive an error with record. areas (The name 'record' does not exist in the current context).

Also in this form would the data be able to be sorted in any way by using actual written code as I am trying to avoid using the default inbuilt Visual Studio sorting method.

Comment: I think I fixed the `record.` issue. For sorting, see my main method for examples, but you could also do it manually if you really need to.

Comment: Yet another error (sorry I'm having to constantly refer back but since I didn't write the code I'm having to slowly figure out how it all works which is awkward to say the least).

Upon the code hitting 'int month = int.Parse(monthRdr.ReadLine());' I receive a System.FormatException error with the information that the input string wasn't in the correct format.

Comment: What do your months looks like?

Comment: Nevermind... I think I know. Updating code now, check back in a few minutes.

Comment: Oh ok. But as a reference the months are written in full form (January, February, March, etc)